# SQL Server - Getting a result after one result matches what you need

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data:

```
DateTime                     Name           EventName    ReasonText    
2020-07-01 09:57:41.007      Joe Smith      Ready        Ready         
2020-07-01 09:57:47.000      Joe Smith      Not Ready    Pre-Shift
```

I am attempting to figure out this: Return the result in which analyst went into 'Ready' state and then 'Pre-Shift'

or

Return the result in which EventName and ReasonText= Ready and following result is EventName 'Not Ready' and ReasonText 'Pre-Shift'

Tables and columns used for this:

AST(EventName)
RC(ReasonText)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is you input like? What is the expected result? The `Name`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `lead()`:

> Return the result in which EventName and ReasonText= Ready and following result is EventName 'Not Ready' and ReasonText 'Pre-Shift'

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(eventname) over (partition by name order by datetime) as next_eventname,
             lead(ReasonText) over (partition by name order by datetime) as next_ReasonText
      from t
     ) t
where eventname = 'Ready' and
      ReasonText = 'Ready' and
      next_eventname = 'Not Ready' and
      next_ReasonText = 'Pre-Shift';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to try this :)